# Grid Layout in Recycler view is cutting of the first two items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a `Recycler view` that hold a `Grid Layout` to present the items in a 2 by 2 way.
The problem is that the first two items are not stretching accordingly with the content inside. To easy the explanation here is one **example** of my problem:

[image: Grid recycler view]

Regarding the code, in my `item.xml` I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/dialog_background_color"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light">

        <TextView
                style="@style/SubtitleStyle"
                android:id="@+id/vExpenseType"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vExpenseImage"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vExpenseImage"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vExpenseImage"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vExpenseImage"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_debt"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is my `main.xml` that hold the `recycler view`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#CC000000"
        tools:context=".ui.flows.main.fragments.overview.OverviewMainInputExpenseDialog">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_dialog"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                style="@style/ButtonLabelStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
                android:text="Choose"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vMovementTypeRv"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/vMovementTypeRv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                tools:spanCount="2"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_expense_type"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in my respective `class` I have :

```
vMovementTypeRv.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext,2)
```

**Final conclusions**

I tried to change the layout but I am not able to make this work. Can someone show me some input on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for showing 2 by 2 items. And you need to show the `RecyclerView` for items showing and delete the `spanCount`.

```
vMovementTypeRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 4));
vMovementTypeRv.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: What do you say by delete the ''spanCount''

Comment: @JoséNobre  When you make something in the `java` do not use it again in the `xml`  and you need to delete the `tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"`